# How to predict output due to some variables out of all variables which affect it?

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have some variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6$ (may be correlated with each other) and my dependent variable is $Y$.

I want to know the contribution of two groups $X_1,X_2,X_3$ and $X_4,X_5,X_6$ to $Y$ separately, i.e. given only values of $X_1,X_2,X_3$, what will be the predicted $Y$?

Is this same as calculating importance matrix? Or what other approach should I use? This is not a linear regression problem, but if it was, I could have used regression coefficients directly, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ANOVA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r) in this case to get the relation between different features(categorical variables) within them and with respect to the target variable.

If you want to check the feature importance with respect to target variable then you can this package [Boruta](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/select-important-variables-boruta-package/) in R, implementable in python too.

If you want to know more, which test when can you use it, go through this [link](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/whatstat/what-statistical-analysis-should-i-usestatistical-analyses-using-spss/)

Do let me know if you have any doubts!

Comment: was my answer helpful, if yes, +1 is appreciated. Thank you